# Trying to advance a simple_form's time field to display the object's time +/- x hours

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

I have a simple_nest_form for an event with many occurrences in rails 3.1.3. For persisted objects, :from and :to are stored as DateTime in UTC. On the edit page I display the :from and :to as H:M (with date handled separately). I'm trying to to set the display of the time to either 1hr before or 1hr after the persisted time. I've tried modifying of.object's attributes which appear to be immutable and I've tried passing various combinations input_html options without success. I haven't found any options or docs to make this modification, any thoughts?

```
<%= f.fields_for :occurrences do |of| %>
  <%= of.input :from, :as => :time, label: "From", :ampm => true, :minute_step => 15, :prompt => { :hour => "Hour", :minute => false }, :required => false %>
  <%= of.input :to, :as => :time, label: "To", :ampm => true, :minute_step => 15, :prompt => { :hour => "Hour", :minute => false }, :required => false %>
```

Comment: Here is related issue https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/issues/1328